# The natural map $\text{Spec}A_f\to \text{Spec}A$ is a homeomorphism onto $D(f)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $f\in A$ a non-nilpotent element. Then the set $\text{Spec}A_f$ has a natural one-to-one correspondence with the subset $D(f)\subset \text{Spec}A$ consisting of all $\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}A$ with $f\notin \mathfrak{p}$. So $D(f)$ is an open subset of $\text{Spec}A$. Is it true that the natural map $\text{Spec}A_f\to \text{Spec}A$ is a homeomorphism onto $D(f)$? (I merely know that this map is a continuous injection onto $D(f)$.)

Comment: I may be misremembering, but maps between affine schemes are uniquely determined by the underlying maps on the global sections, are they not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we prove that $D(f)\backsimeq\operatorname{Spec} A_f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492327/how-can-we-prove-that-df-backsimeq-operatornamespec-a-f)

Comment: Do you already know that sets of the form $D(f)$ are a basis for the topology of $\operatorname{Spec} A$? With this you can show that the basic opens of $\operatorname{Spec}(A_f)$  are also basic opens of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$.